# Calling Struts 2 action class from AngularJS with HTTP GET request but not getting any response

Tags: java, angularjs, json, jsp, struts2

I am creating a simple application, that make a simple call to action of Struts 2 via AngularJS. I just create a simple HTTP GET request from AngularJS to get JSON from the server. At server end I am using Struts2 action class named as `AngularAction.java`.

But, all the time I am unable to hit the class, even I had print some dummy message at the action class but could not find anything.

**Code files are:**

**`index.jsp`**
(index page from where I am sending a HTTP GET request to Struts class via AngularJS)

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("controller", function($scope,$http){
        $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
        
            $http.get("angularAction").success(
                    function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.person = data;
                    }).error(function(data, statusenter code here, headers, config) {
                                    console.log("error message " + data);
            });
    };  
            
    });
        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp"  >
        <div ng-controller="controller" >
                <button ng-click="getDataFromServer()">
                     Fetch data from server
                </button>
                <p> First Name : {{person.firstName}} </p>
                <p> Last Name : {{person.lastName}} </p>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`AngularAction.java`:**
(Struts action class)

```java
public class AngularAction extends ActionSupport {

    PersonData personData ;
    
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
         personData.setFirstName("test");
         personData.setLastName("base");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public PersonData getPersonData() {
        return personData;
    }
    public void setPersonData(PersonData personData) {
        this.personData = personData;
    }

}
```

**`struts.xml`:**
(Struts configuration file)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="json-default">
            <action  name="angularAction"  class="com.action.AngularAction" >
                <result type="json" >
                      <param name="root">personData</param>
                      <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
                      <param name="noCache">true</param>
                </result>
            </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: Your `personData` is null.

Comment: No i am not able to hit my action class. Is there anything wrong in mapping ?

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that `personData` is null. See dev tool of your browser to where request is going.

Comment: If you configured `PersonData` with Spring it will be injected at the action attribute. Did you use it?

Comment: Lets suppose there is no personData in action class then also it not working for me..

Comment: @sandeeprawat You should initialize `personData ` first because it will not work because it's not done. Next see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `personData` in either way, using parameter, container injection, manually because you will get `NullPointerException` in the `execute()` method.

Struts2 uses action mapping to the URL to execute the action method. Action mapping has properties such as namespace, action name, parameters. When the URL is parsed the action mapping object is created and then it's used to determine the action config. If not the action config is found you should get 404 error `There's no action mapped for the action name [] and namespace [] in the context []`.

From the `struts.xml` you have defined two attributes: the action name and namespace. Remains to define the third attribute - context.

The name of the JSP is `index.jsp` if it's not a welcome file then you can use struts tags inside it, such as `s:url` if this page is returned as a result of the index action. Here the example of such action from the Struts2 Hello World application

```
<action name="index">
  <result>/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you are using `index.jsp` as welcome file, which is used by default in most web servers, then you have to provide the context path to the action URL.

```
app.controller("controller", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
    $http.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/angularAction")
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.person = response.data;
      }, function(response) {
        console.log("error message: " + response.statusText);
    });
  };
}]);
```

Make sure that `struts.xml` is found and parsed by Struts and Struts filter is mapped to handle all requests.

Comment: @sandeeprawat You can accept the answer if that helped.